# Disable password authtication for web interface using configuration in HELM valus.yaml when SAML SSO is configured

Tags: gitlab-api, gitlab-omnibus

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYorO.png)

Manually this option can be selected in admin settings. But how to configure it via configuration

Now its manually configured. API config should also workout. Please let me know if there is a API call for the same.